# What is the correct way to utilize Jquery UI bundled with Yii?

Tags: php, jquery-ui, yii

I've been trying to make sense of Jquery UI and using Yii's inbuilt version for a while now and I'm still confused. Can anyone confirm the correct way to implement this?

**To tie this down further as requested**

Where is the Jquery UI saved within the framework files? How do I register the scripts and CSS files? I keep finding conflicting advice on how to do this.

Comment: What exacly is your problem? What confuses you?

Comment: The files are saved in `framework/web/js/source/jui/`. Use `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery.ui')` to embed a link to the relevant JS file into your HTML template.

Comment: Thanks DCoder, what about css files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, register jquery UI

```
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCoreScript('jquery.ui');
```

Then create new jQuery UI theme (http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) and store it to directory (for example vendors)

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile(
    Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(Yii::app()->basePath . '/vendors/your_theme/')
    . '/jquery-ui.custom.css', 'screen');
```

Or you can use default yii theme:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile(
    Yii::app()->clientScript->getCoreScriptUrl().'/jui/css/base/jquery-ui.css');
```